# Ansible - choose the most recently updated side and synchronize the local and remote directories?

Tags: ansible, rsync, data-synchronization

I have several workstations with a similar setup (home computer, workstation at the office) and also a server that is used as a remote storage. I'm trying to make `Ansible` to backup and synchronize several application profile directories (Intellij Idea profile dir, my desktop environment profile dir, some applications unpacked from tar.gz distributions and so on) between these devices. I never use all devices at the same time.

The logic for every dir should be:

- check local directory modification timestamp
- check modification timestamp of a directory on the remote server
- if local copy is older, overwrite it with contents of a directory on the remote server. Otherwise, backup contents of local directory to a remote directory (effectively overwriting it).

I'm going to use `Ansible` with `synchronize` module. But implementing the logic above using `when` for every folder in my (rather long) list sounds like inventing a bycicle to me. It should be a better way to accomplish that.

Seems like a common task, maybe there is a third-party Ansible role/plugin that does that? Or maybe a separate application that may be called using `command`?

Comment: You could play with loops (with_item, with_together) defining directory list or dictionary somewhere.

Comment: Rsync isn't really a great two-way synchronization tool. Have you considered something like [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)?

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look on it. But  at first glance, it is not a console solution that can be easily integrated with Ansible

Comment: ansible isn't the best tool for it. What you should use is a version control tool like git. You are describing the problem version control resolves.

Comment: Files are mostly binary. I've considered using git LFS, but it sounds like overkill for this task. I don't need versioning, don't want to run git server all the time, don't need to waste space on old versions of files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible is obviously not the appropriate tool for this.

Why don't you use an online storage service with folder sync capabilities, like Dropbox?